# Fetch username from another table into a table containing two field that has UserID

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables i.e `tblUser` and `tblForward` with the following columns:

**tblUser**:

```
UserID             
Username
```

**tblForward**:

```
ForwardID     
ForwardedToUserID  (--> tblUser.UserID)
ForwardedFromUserID  (--> tblUser.UserID)
```

Now what I want to do is to fetch the `Username` from `tblUser` using the `ForwardedToUserID` and `ForwardedFromUserID` and display `Username` (not `UserID`) when I fetch data from `tblForward`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need to use a "join". Try searching for "sql join" for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN OP want to connect `ForwardedToUserID and ForwardedFromUserID`

```
select max(Fromuser),max(ToUser) from (
  select UserName as Fromuser, '' as ToUser from tblUsers A  
  inner join  tblForward B ON A.UserID = B.ForwardedToUserID 
  union all
  select '' as Fromuser, UserName as ToUser  from tblUsers A  
  inner join  tblForward B ON A.UserID = B.ForwardedFromUserID) as t
```

Comment: this gives a list of names but how do i identify which user is forwardedto username and which username is forwardedfrom?.

Comment: @TashiTobgay now check it

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you this:

```
SELECT A.UserName, B.UserName AS ForwardedToUserName, C.UserName AS ForwardedFromUserName
FROM tblUsers A 
    INNER JOIN tblForward B ON A.UserID = B.ForwardedToUserID
    INNER JOIN tblForward C ON A.UserID = C.ForwardedFromUserID
```

because it return associated username for all userid's

Comment: thanks, this fetches username from the tblUsers with associated UserID. Now how do i combine this usernames with the data fetched from the tblForward?.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is using a [join statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT A.UserName from tblUsers A 
inner join tblForward B on 
     A.UserID = B.ForwardedToUserID
     OR A.UserID = B.ForwardedFromUserID
```

Comment: I want to fetch data from tblForward, right now it is giving me UserID inside the 'ForwardedToUserID' and 'ForwardedFromUserID'. I want to display names and other data when i fetch data from tblForward.

Comment: @TashiTobgay, I've noticed that you added the **c#** tag, are you facing problem in getting the result of your select into your application, or is it a select statement problem ?  please clarify your question to avoid down-votes, add relevant codes, and point out your issue